# Setting the domain for a cookie doesn't create the cookie in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC app which uses WebAPI for data access.
Token based authentication is implemented for securing the WebAPIs.

Here is the code that get's the token and writes it to a cookie:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
var client = new OAuth2Client(new Uri(tokenEndpoint));
var tokenResponse = client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(studentId + ":"+ defaultStudent, tokenPassword).Result;
HttpCookie tokenCookie = new HttpCookie("AuthCookie", tokenResponse.AccessToken);
tokenCookie.Domain = "localhost:88888";
tokenCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(tokenCookie);
}
```

So the idea here is that I want only my API domain, api.contoso.com for example, to only read that cookie.

If the Domain part is commented then the cookie get's written.
How do I set the domain for this cookie?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Remove the port number from the domain. A cookie is specific to domain not its port or protocol. Im pretty sure IE will refuse to send a cookie with a port number included yet chrome and firefox will.

Comment: hmm try setting this to 127.0.0.1 instead and see if that works

Comment: If you do not specify the domain it will just be your current domain. Is there a particular reason you want to set this? Moving your site would require code changes and so on...

Comment: Nope does not, in fact it doesn't work not matter what the values is. Updated the question for the requirement.

Comment: how exactly are you checking to see if the cookie has been written? you need to wait for the NEXT request to read the cookie once the previous response has been written.

Comment: You cant set a cookie for a different domain :/ This would be a massive security issue. You can set it for a sub domain though. Localhost cannot write a cookie to api.contoso.com. If you want to set a cookie for all subdomains just set .contoso.com as the domain

Comment: @heymega can you please point me to some links that explain the security issue.

Comment: Its the same origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy .